# Android device acting as an accessory

Tags: android, usb

I have 2 Android devices, which I would like to connect with a USB OTG cable and have back-and-forth communication between the two devices.  From what I understand, one Android device will act as the USB Host (Nexus 7 running 4.4) and the other Android device will act as a USB Accessory (Galaxy Nexus running 4.2.2).  I've tried googling around for an answer, but I can only seem to find articles explaining how to connect an Android device to a USB accessory (like a USB mouse or keyboard), not how to treat an Android device as the USB accessory itself.

So, following [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) page, I have configured an app on the Nexus 7 to be the USB Host.  I can find the connected Galaxy Nexus based on its product id & vendor id, form a connection to the Android Open Accessory Protocol and successfully connect over USB.  From what I can tell, the Nexus 7 can successfully send bytes to the Galaxy Nexus.

My question is how to access this connection on the Galaxy Nexus side.  I have added permissions and the USB filter into the manifest, so the desired app opens on the Galaxy Nexus once the USB connection is established, but I can't figure out how to receive the data coming in from the Nexus 7 or how to send data from the Galaxy Nexus back to the Nexus 7.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Whoever called this off topic is severely mistaken.  This concerns **software development** utilizing the **android APIs**.

Comment: There is no generic "USB device" API in Android for operating as a USB slave.  Your best best is probably to look at the ADK protocol - have the "host" device play the role of the external embedded USB host (ie, the job normally done by the ADK board, Arduino + USB host shield, or ioio board).  Then you can use the ADK APIs on the "slave" device.

Answer (score 0):

See my SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21501914/1172181).

If you want the Galaxy Nexus to act as the USB Accessory, then it must implement the Android Open Accessory protocol. An Android Accessory is a usb host, so technically you would have two hosts (assuming you managed to implement correctly the AOA protocol on the Galaxy Nexus), which is clearly a deviation of the USB spec.